# Dúvida de HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Olá, sou novo em programação e estava tentando criar um programa. O aplicativo que uso para rodar HTML5 comunicou um erro na linha 25 e na 28. Na linha 25 eu coloquei onclick em uma form de submit e entre a s aspas botei o nome de uma função. O erro na linha 28 foi por causa do documento.getElementById(). Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Cups</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: orange;
            }

            p {
                text-indent: 10%;
            }

            .a {
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi. This program give the number of needed cups to make a tower. The input is the number of cups in the base.</p>
        <span class="a">Input:</span>
        <label>Cups in base:</label>
        <input id="input" type="text"/><br/>
        <input id="input0" type="submit" onclick="program()"/>
        <script>
            function program() {
                int a = document.getElementById("input");
                int b = a;
                while(b > 1) {
                    b = b - 1;
                    a = a + b;
                }
            }
            document.write(a);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nao seria `document.getElementById("input").value` ?

Comment: Se vc retirar `int` antes de `a` e de `b`,  jogar `document.write(a);` dentro da função e pegar o valor com `document.getElementById("input").value;` vai rodar

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos bem do básico:

1. Se você esta aprendendo a programar, não use mais o `var`. Use `let` ou `const` para declarar uma variável em Javascript. Um dos maiores problemas que você vai encontrar com o var, é a regra de escopo. Isso é um grande problema na linguagem e já foi corrigido.
2. Ao declarar a variável para puxar o elemento do DOM, ou seja, do input, você precisa colocar o .value, ficando da seguinte forma:

   let a = document.getElementById('input').value
3. Eu tentei com a alert, mas você pode usar o innerHTML para inserir um elemento no DOM. Ficando da seguinte forma:

   document.getElementByID('nomeDoElemento').innerHTML = 'resultado'
4. como você delarou o `let a` dentro da função, ela agora tem uma regra de escopo.

Script final:

```
<script>
        function program() {
            let a = document.getElementById('input').value
            let b = a
            while (b > 1) {
                b = b - 1
                a = a + b
            }
            alert(a)
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: O único problema que tive depois foi o sistema tratar a como string, mas bastou eu usar let a = Number(document.getElementById("input").value).

Comment: Ah sim! Você tmbém pode user esse processo. Chamado de Casting!

Answer (score 0):

Problemas:

- JavaScript é uma linguagem fracamente tipada, você cria uma variável com `var a` ou `let a` e não `int a`
- Pegue o valor do elemento, ao fazer `document.getElementById()` você está pegando uma referência ao elemento não o seu valor
- O `document.writer()` deve ficar dentro da função

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Cups</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: orange;
            }

            p {
                text-indent: 10%;
            }

            .a {
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi. This program give the number of needed cups to make a tower. The input is the number of cups in the base.</p>
        <span class="a">Input:</span>
        <label>Cups in base:</label>
        <input id="input" type="text"/><br/>
        <input id="input0" type="submit" onclick="program()"/>
        <script>
            function program() {
                let a = document.getElementById("input").value;
                var b = a;
                while(b > 1) {
                    b = b - 1;
                    a = a + b;
                }
                document.write(a);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Nem sei como não percebi que o documento.write() estava fora da function.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Cups</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    
    p {
      text-indent: 10%;
    }
    
    .a {
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hi. This program give the number of needed cups to make a tower. The input is the number of cups in the base.</p>
  <span class="a">Input:</span>
  <label>Cups in base:</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" /><br/>
  <button type="button" id="input0">result</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear">Limpar</button>
  <div id="result" value="">
  </div>
  <script>
    var $button = document.querySelector("#input0");
    var $buttonClear = document.querySelector("#clear");

    $button.addEventListener('click', function() {

      let a = document.querySelector("#input").value;

      var b = a;

      while (b > 1) {

        b = b - 1;

        a = a + b;
      }

      document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = a;

    }, false);

    $buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {

      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = '';

      document.querySelector("#input").value = '';

    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

é boa praticar evitar js in line e o uso do document.write, use console.log() para depuração